# How can I fix properties of object in array of objects?

Tags: javascript, loops

I have the following array. The problem that I have space in the beginnig of **`eng`** and **`otherLang`** property in some objects. How can I fix it?

```
[ 
  { id: 8854, eng: "General Manager", otherLang: "General Manager" }, 
  { id: 24, eng: " Main Specialist", otherLang: " Main Specialist" } 
]
```

I tried this so far.

```
array.map(item => {return {...item, eng: item.eng.trim()}}
```

THanks everyone who suggested! My solution worked and yours suggestions helped my to apply it properly. Don't know why but VSCODE highlighted this piece of code so I thought its wrong.

Comment: Do what you did for `eng` but this time for `otherLang`? `...item, eng: item.eng.trim(), otherLang: item.otherLang.trim() }}`?

Comment: You need to assign the value returned by `map` to a variable. `let updatedArray = array.map(item => ..)`It won't update the original array. Is this your issue?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes looks like it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A naive approach would be to repeat what you already did with `eng`:

```js
const array = [{
    id: 8854,
    eng: "General Manager",
    otherLang: "General Manager"
  },
  {
    id: 24,
    eng: " Main Specialist",
    otherLang: " Main Specialist"
  }
];

console.log(
  array.map(item => {
    return {
      ...item,
      eng: item.eng.trim(),
      otherLang: item.otherLang.trim()
    }
  })
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do it for all "string" values in one go:

```js
const input = [ 
  { id: 8854, eng: "General Manager", otherLang: "General Manager" }, 
  { id: 24, eng: " Main Specialist", otherLang: " Main Specialist" } 
]

const result = input.map(
  i => Object.fromEntries( 
          Object.entries(i).map( ([k,v]) => typeof v === "string" ? [k,v.trim()] : [k,v] ) 
       )
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed on round bracket at the end

```
array.map(item => {return {...item, eng: item.eng.trim(),otherLang:item.otherLang.trim()}})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following way trimming both the object properties:

```js
var array = [ 
  { id: 8854, eng: "General Manager", otherLang: "General Manager" }, 
  { id: 24, eng: " Main Specialist", otherLang: " Main Specialist" } 
]

var res = array.map(item => ({...item, eng: item.eng.trim(),otherLang: item.otherLang.trim()}));
console.log(res);
```